# magento: my "custom url rewrites" for menu are gone

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

I created these categories, intended for the sub-menu to point to specific URL I desired.

Company
   |-------Contact Us
   |-------About Us

When clicked on 'Contact Us', I want it to go to "~/magento/contacts".
But it actually went to `"~/magento/company/contacts.html"`

So, after research, i set up the "URL Rewrite Management", and it worked then. 
But after a few hours, my "**Custom URL Rewrites**" was somehow removed, and replaced with the original system generated URL.

(This seems happening after `*reindexing*` )

What did i miss? How to permanent rewrite URL?

[Screen Shots: my URL rewrites steps.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFhig.png)

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408213/magento-1-7-0-2-index-management-overwriting-url-rewrites

> 1. Create new page
> 2. Go to "URL Rewrite" and note the ID Path of the new category
> 3. Delete the system generated URL Rewrite
> 4. Create a "custom" Rewrite specifying the "ID Path" of the deleted object, The request path, and then the path to the desired URL
> 5. Go to phpmyadmin > core_url_rewrite and find the newly created custom Rewrite
> 6. Change the store_id to 0 (not changing anything else)
> 7. Reindex. This creates a new system generated Rewrite with a higher url_rewrite_id (see in phpmyadmin > core_url_rewrite table)
> 8. I then create my page with the desired path
> 9. Reindex / flush caches and presto.. my top nav now has a menu item to my new page.